# json_decode with array and objects

Tags: php, arrays, json, object, decode

I have JSON that I need to get some information from.

```
<?

$json = {"ship":{"shipname":"Harbinger Navy Issue","shipid":"33155","dna":"33155:3520;6:11561;1:19280;1:19278;1:4349;1:19191;1:2364;2:1248;3:2048;1:31372;3:2488;10:12814;6::"},"high":[{"Heavy Pulse Laser II:3520":6}],"medium":[{"Shield Boost Amplifier I:11561":1},{"Pith A-Type EM Ward Field:19280":1},{"Pith A-Type Thermic Dissipation Field:19278":1},{"Pithum C-Type Adaptive Invulnerability Field:4349":1},{"Pithum A-Type Medium Shield Booster:19191":1}],"low":[{"Heat Sink II:2364":2},{"Capacitor Flux Coil II:1248":3},{"Damage Control II:2048":1}],"rig":[{"Medium Capacitor Control Circuit I:31372":3}],"subsystem":[],"drones":[{"Warrior II:2488":10}],"charge":[{"Conflagration M:12814":6}]};

$obj_o = json_decode($json);
$test = $obj_o->ship->shipname;
$test2 = $obj_o->high->{0};
$test3 = $obj_o->ship->high->{0}->{0};
$test4 = $obj_O->ship->dna;
$test5 = $obj_a[high][1];
//$test6 = $obj_a[medium][1]{1};

$test6 = $result->ship->shipname;

echo 'test6:';
echo $test6;
echo '</br>';
echo 'test5:';
echo $test5;
echo '</br>';
echo $test;
echo '</br>';
echo 'test2:';
echo $test2;
echo '</br>';
echo 'test3:';
echo $test3;
echo '</br>';

?>
```

I want to select "high" from the JSON and split it into 3 parts:

1. Heavy Pulse Laser II
2. 3520
3. 6

How do I do this?

Comment: `$json = {"ship":"foo"};` is neither valid PHP nor valid JSON. Please extract a minimal example before posting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: If you want it returned as an array:

```
$obj_o = json_decode($json, true);
foreach($obj_o["high"] as $key => $value){
    $keyArray = explode(":", $key);
    //$keyArray[0] is 'High Pulse Laser II'
    //$keyArray[1] is 3520
    //$value is 6
}
```

If you want an object:

```
$obj_o = json_decode($json);
foreach($obj_o->high as $weapon) {
    foreach($weapon as $key => $value) {
        $keyArray = explode(":", $key);
        //$keyArray[0] is 'High Pulse Laser II'
        //$keyArray[1] is 3520
        //$value is 6   
    }
}
```

Comment: When i use this then comes

Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /var/customers/webs/ni7/Eve/Eft/display.php on line 95

and with json_decode($json, true)

$keyArray[0] as echo

Comment: @James Spence, `json_decode` returns an object of type stdClass and not a php array. If you want to return a php array you need to add `true` as a second parameter i.e `json_decode($myjson, true)`

Comment: when i json_decode($json, true) then come only by echo bsp.
echo $keyArray[0]; result is  0 
and by echo $value; is the result: Array
not that wat i need ( High Pulse Laser II) , 3520, 6

Comment: Answer updated. I just ran your code as you have it. See "if you want an object".

Comment: The Code Help me a Lot ! Thanks Thanks Thanks only one question i have then the high has 2 Arrays how it works with tihs ??
i have try it with
"medium" my result is `
keyarray0: Pithum A-Type Medium Shield Booster
keyarray1: 19191
value: 1`
but the array 2 cant display

Comment: ok i have the problem i solved thanks :)
VERY VERY VERY VERY THANKS for the FAST Help this is awesome :)
Big Thanks to @James Spence